# php: simplexml_load_file check server status

Tags: php, simplexml

i load file from server:

```
$url = 'http://www.sample.com/test.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

And if servers is close i get error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:...
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity
```

how to check if the file is reached?

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual page for `simplexml_load_file`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

> Returns an object of class `SimpleXMLElement` with properties containing the data held within the XML document. On errors, it will return `FALSE`.

which means you can do

```
$url = 'http://www.sample.com/test.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

// check what was returned
if(FALSE === $xml) {
    echo 'could not open file';
}
```